# What does 初期运营速度 mean when we talk about high speed railway?

Tags: vocabulary

When talking about the definition of high speed railway, it is often said 初期运营速度不小于200公里/小时. I don't understand what 初期运营速度 mean? I come out a few possible meanings, but not sure which is correct.

- Option 1: The designed speed (if so, it implies the real running speed might be either faster or slower)
- Option 2: the speed of early stage (if so, it implies there will be a later stage of this railway and in later stage the running speed will be either faster or slower.)
- Option 3: the starting speed when a train departs from the railway platform.

Comment: Option 2. And I suppose the speed will be faster when in the stable phase.

Comment: 初期 always means early stage

Comment: I know it means "early stage". I am not sure what type of stage it refers to. A train's departing is the early stage of its journey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

初期运营速度 means operative speed in early phase. The early phase could be a trial run to see if everything works okay. And later on, they might increase the speed based on the data they collected from that trial run, or they would fix if any issues are identified.